# Implemeting a User Class that supports multiple login methods

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I've got a parent class `User` that has two child classes `User_Instagram` and `User_Email`. I use these classes to support multiple login methods: a user can choose to login using Instagram, Email, or even both (once using email, and then using Instagram later).

The `User_Instagram` class contains the Instagram-specific user parameters (like InstagramUserId, Bio, etc.). The `User_Email` class is used for typical signups using an email/password combo.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this in a way that is OOP-complaint. I need to be able to:

1. Register a user by calling `User_Instagram->register($token)` or `User_Email->register($email,$password)`
2. Instantiate a `User` class in order to be able to access the general user information (like the `$userid`) and in order to know which services he's logged into (email, Instagram or both).

The way I've currently implemented is a bit hard to maintain - and I'm pretty sure is just plain wrong (call it a gut feeling).

### Current Class Structure

The parent class

```
class User {
    protected $userid = NULL;
    protected $loggedInServices = array('instagram'=>0,'email'=>1);
    ...
}
```

And the child classes:

```
class User_Instagram extends User {
    private $instagram_userid;
    private $bio;
    private $profile_pic;
    private $token;
    ...

    public function signIn( $token ) { ... }
    public function register( $token ) { ... }
}

class User_Email extends User {
    private $email;
    private $password; # hashed, of course ;)

    public function signIn( $email, $password) { ... }
    public function register( $email, $password, $passport_number) { ... }
}
```

I initially thought a Factory class might work here, but the parent class cannot be instantiated in that scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to inherit from a user class to implement a login process. I would change it to something like that:

```
class User {
    protected $userid = NULL;
    public function setUserId($id) { ... }
    ...
}

class Login_Instagram {
    private $instagram_userid;
    private $bio;
    private $profile_pic;
    private $token;
    ...

    public function __construct(User $user) { ... }
    public function signIn( $token ) { ... $user->setUserId($id); ... }
    public function register( $token ) { ... }
}

class Login_Email {
    private $email;

    public function __construct(User $user) { ... }
    public function signIn( $email, $password) { ... $user->setUserId($id); ... }
    public function register( $email, $password, $passport_number) { ... }
}
```

To not implement the constructor twice, you could create a parent class for that and even to the setUserId in that parent class. But a login procedure does not need to be in a user class, especially if the process can differ.

Any why do you want to store the password hash in your object? When you have validated the user, just set his user id, you won't need that password hash later.

Comment: But how would I access the Instagram details from the User class? I'd have to add all of those attributes again, in the User class right? That just sounds redundant to me.

Comment: What data do you need? You could still inject that login_instagram object into the user object and access the data from their. But in that case I would consider to even create a new class with the instagram data in it, because you don't want to inject the login process, just the instragram data ;)